# Реагирование на определённый стикер пак (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Итак, есть хендлер, который удаляет стикеры из чата:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(msg):
    bot.delete_message(msg.chat.id, msg.message_id)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "without sticker's" + c)
```

но он удаляет все стикеры, а необходимо удаление нескольких определённых паков. возможно ли реализовать такое? В документации телеграмма находил что-то про `stickerset.name`, но это ничем мне не помогло.

Comment: Если мой склероз меня не подводит, должно быть что-то такое: `sticker_id = bot.get_file(msg.sticker.file_id)`.

Comment: @strawdog так он получает id определённого стикера из пака, и если необходимо запретить пак в сотню стикеров... геморрно будет запрещать каждый стикер. да и даже так, он выдаёт строчку `{'file_id': 'CAADAgADOAADyIsGAAE7re09I3hMQwI', 'file_size': 43636, 'file_path': 'stickers/file_3.webp'}` и просто проверка на file_id не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `msg.sticker.set_name` хранится название стикер-пака

`@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def handle_sticker(msg):
    if msg.sticker.set_name in ['name_sticker_pack_1', 'name_sticker_pack_2', ...]:
        bot.delete_message(msg.chat.id, msg.message_id)`

Лямбду можешь убрать, т.к. хандлер сработает только на стикер